# ¿Cómo enlazar un determinado activity a su itemlist correspondiente de un recycleview?

Tags: java, android-studio, recyclerview, android-recyclerview, switch

es decir que un elemento del recycleview me mande a un activity correspondiente, por ejemplo el primer itemList del recycleview me mande al activity 1, el segundo itemList me mande al activity 2 y así sucesivamente.. he intentado definirlo con un **switch(position)**, pero tengo algunos errores al momento de declararlo. bueno les dejo mi parte del código, espero puedan ayudarme. gracias.

```
public class contenido_basico extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerItemClick {

    private RecyclerView rvLista;
    private RecyclerAdapter adapter;
    private List<ItemList> items;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contenido_basico);

        initViews();
        initValues();

    }


    private void initViews(){
        rvLista = findViewById(R.id.rvLista);
    }

    private void initValues(){
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvLista.setLayoutManager(manager);

        items = getItems();
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(items,this);
        rvLista.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private List<ItemList> getItems() {
        List<ItemList> itemLists = new ArrayList<>();
```

> en esta parte tengo declarada el itemlist de los elementos que muestra el recyview, los cuales son 12,

```
        itemLists.add(new ItemList("Titulo del Tema 1", "Descripcion del tema a ver.", R.drawable.transparent_b));
        itemLists.add(new ItemList("Titulo del Tema 2", "Descripcion del tema a ver.", R.drawable.transparent_b));
        itemLists.add(new ItemList("Titulo del Tema 3", "Descripcion del tema a ver.", R.drawable.transparent_b));
        itemLists.add(new ItemList("Titulo del Tema 4", "Descripcion del tema a ver.", R.drawable.transparent_b));
        itemLists.add(new ItemList("Titulo del Tema 5", "Descripcion del tema a ver.", R.drawable.transparent_b));
        itemLists.add(new ItemList("Titulo del Tema 6", "Descripcion del tema a ver.", R.drawable.transparent_b));
        itemLists.add(new ItemList("Titulo del Tema 7", "Descripcion del tema a ver.", R.drawable.transparent_b));
        itemLists.add(new ItemList("Titulo del Tema 8", "Descripcion del tema a ver.", R.drawable.transparent_b));
        itemLists.add(new ItemList("Titulo del Tema 9", "Descripcion del tema a ver.", R.drawable.transparent_b));
        itemLists.add(new ItemList("Titulo del Tema 10", "Descripcion del tema a ver.", R.drawable.transparent_b));
        itemLists.add(new ItemList("Titulo del Tema 11", "Descripcion del tema a ver.", R.drawable.transparent_b));
        itemLists.add(new ItemList("Titulo del Tema 12", "Descripcion del tema a ver.", R.drawable.transparent_b));

        return itemLists;
    }
```

> y en esta parte tengo mi intento de swithc(position) el cual me marca errores, lo que pretendo es que se valide el ítem seleccionado del ItemList y de acuerdo a ello lanzar el activity correspondiente.

```
    @Override
    public void itemClick(ItemList item) {

        switch (position) {

            case 1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity1.class);
         break;

            case 2:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity2.class);
         break;

            case 3:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity3.class);
                break;

            case 4:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity4.class);
                break;

            case 5:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity5.class);
                break;

            case 6:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity6.class);
                break;

            case 7:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity7.class);
                break;

            case 8:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity8.class);
                break;
            case 9:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity9.class);
                break;

            case 10:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity10.class);
                break;

            case 11:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity11.class);
                break;

            case 12:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity12.class);
                break;
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }


    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
      public void Anterior(View view) {
        Intent anterior = new Intent(this, Curso.class);
        startActivity(anterior);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Podrìas poner el còdigo del adaptador?

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que tu adaptador es algo así:

```
public class TuAdaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TuAdaptador.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<TuClase> arrayTuClase;
    private Context context;

//resto de tu adaptador

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {//manejamos el evento del click

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int itemPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            if(tuarray.get(itemPosition) == 1){ acá pones tu intent a la clase que deseas }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es el código de mi Adapter.

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerHolder> {
private List<ItemList> items;
private RecyclerItemClick itemClick;

public RecyclerAdapter(List<ItemList> items, RecyclerItemClick itemClick) {
    this.items = items;
    this.itemClick = itemClick;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_view,parent, false);
    return new RecyclerHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerHolder holder, int position) {
     final ItemList item = items.get(position);
     holder.imgItem.setImageResource(item.getImgResource());
     holder.tvTitulo.setText(item.getTitulo());
     holder.tvDescripcion.setText(item.getDescripcion());

     holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             itemClick.itemClick(item);
         }
     });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
```

> esto ya no lo utilizo, pero lo utilize para mandar los parametro de dos text views y una imageview en un .xml

```
public static class RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ImageView imgItem;
    private TextView tvTitulo;
    private TextView tvDescripcion;

    public RecyclerHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imgItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgItem);
        tvTitulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
        tvDescripcion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion);

    }
}
```

> aqui esta declardo el ItemClick que estoy utilizando en mi switch(position)

```
public  interface RecyclerItemClick {
    void itemClick(ItemList item);
}
```

Comment: Es respuesta o parte de tu pregunta?

Comment: Es parte de su pregunta

Comment: hola, es parte de la pregunta,  todo eso es mi adapter, pero entonces se declara en el adapter y no en el activity?

Comment: Prueba añadiendo lo que te mostrè en mi respuesta, particularmente yo prefiero hacerlo desde el adaptador pero se puede desde el activity